# Safari resends same form after redirect

Tags: safari

I am currently experiencing a bug that only occurs in the current version of Safari (5.1.5) and was wondering if anyone here could come up with any workarounds for it.  I tested it in 5.1.2 and it worked fine there, I'm not sure about 5.1.3 and 5.1.4 as I don't have access to those releases.

The bug requires three pages, I'll show the source of them and then explain what is going on:

**FirstPageWithForm.htm**

```
<form id="theForm" action="ActionHandler.ashx" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="differentField" value="1234"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="sameField" value="1111"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var theForm = document.getElementById("theForm");
    theForm.submit();
</script>
```

**SecondPageWithForm.htm**

```
<form id="theForm" action="ActionHandler.ashx" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="differentField" value="5678"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="sameField" value="1111"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var theForm = document.getElementById("theForm");
    theForm.submit();
</script>
```

**ActionHandler.ashx**

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
     var referrer = context.Request.UrlReferrer;
     var differentField = context.Request["differentField"];
     context.Response.Write(differentField);
     if (differentField == "1234")
     {
         if (referrer.ToString().Contains("Second"))
             context.Response.Write("Failure");
         else
         {
             context.Response.Redirect("SecondPageWithForm.htm");
         }
     }
     else
        context.Response.Write("Success");
}
```

As you notice both forms have the same field name but one of the fields has a different value.  However, in Safari when this code is run, the value `"1234"` is sent as `differentField` instead of `"5678"`.  I do not believe this bug has anything to do with .NET but I don't have an easy way to test another language to be sure about that.

Things I already tried:

- Putting the form submission code in a function and then calling that.
- Requiring Jquery and calling it in the $(document).ready() function.
- Putting the function call in a setTimeout().
- Replacing the function with a button that I press.
- Copying the Handler and sending the second form to the copy instead.

Every single one of these methods had the same effect, which is to print "Failure" instead of Success.
I will be filing this bug on the Safari forums (I don't have an Apple Developer account and it's not working to create a new one at the moment), but I was hoping that someone could help me come up with a suitable workaround for this problem until they fix it.

EDIT: The Safari forum bug report: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3921507

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NicolasIgot on my safari forum figured out a solution to my problem.

I just added `autocomplete="off"` to the form tag on the second form and everything started working again.  I haven't tried it on my real problem, but it works on my simple test case, so I have confidence in it.